# Kie Server BPM start process via REST

Tags: web-services, rest, drools, jbpm, kie-server

I am trying to start a hello-world process on the Kie server via REST, but with little luck any pointers would be of great help. 
I'm using kie workbench 6.2, kie server 6.2 in wildfly 8.1

Comment: You question is too broad for anybody at Stack Overflow to give you useful help. This is not really a site to go for the kind of step-by-step instructions on how to get started that you seem to want. And answers that just give simple pointers to offsite resources are strongly discouraged. As are questions that ask for those kind of answers.

Answer (score -1):

jBPM , Drools 6 has significant advancements over 5.5 Release.
Here's a nice tutorial to get you started: [Drools KIe Start](http://training-course-material.com/training/JBPM_and_Drools_Introduction#Hello_World_Demo)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its not an answer to the question.